# How to compile and run Google Contacts App in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Could someone please point to some tutorial on how to setup and build the Google's Contact apps which is under packages/apps/Contact and run it in Android Emulator.

I know it has lot of dependencies including the provider itself which is a separate service., and other libraries from the source folder, but what i'm trying to do is to learn the way Google has designed their contact app and use some of its techniques in my app.

Currently i debug manually !! ^-^.. its very very painful, esp following Intent Calls..

but if i were able to compile and build the Contacts app myself, and run it in emulator, i can add some easy debug messages and recompile and then trace them. Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling contacts app nees for Android full source.

1. establish build environment. 
   (Ubuntu 64bit, Git 1.7 or later version, JDK6, Python 2.4~2.7 )
2. get android full source.
   ( http://source.android.com/ )
3. full build with entire source.
   ( http://source.android.com/source/building.html )
4. if full build success, you can partially build each platform apps.
   go to android source root and type in linux command line
   # mmm package/apps/Contacts
5. rooting the Emulator for install system apps.
   and set write privileges to '/system/app' in Emulator.
6. push Contacts.apk into emulator.

Comment: Could you please expand the last two steps. I was successfully able to build android from source and make changes to Contact app, and whenever i try to push the new application to emulator., my contact app in emulator is closed and does not restart. I did not make any changes to source code, i just built the same source code and copied the binary manually to emulator using adb

Comment: step5> I'm using real android device to debug system apps. But if using emulator, there is 2 solutions. one is use emulator image file which result by full source build. Set option 'debug mode' when full source build, the result image has superuser privilege. and the other is using rooting tools.

Comment: and "set write privileges to '/system/app' in Emulator." > when rooted. type this command in windows consol.
" adb shell mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock7 /system" ,
" adb shell chmod 666 /system/app/Contacts.apk "

Comment: 'mtdblock7' is system mounted block. use " adb shell mount" command, and find "/system/app" 's  mount block.

Comment: setp6> remove previous apps and install new one.
" adb shell rm /system/app/Contacts.apk "
" adb shell rm -r /data/dalvik-cache "
" adb push  Contacts.apk /system/app "
" adb reboot"